# APC File Upload Progress Status getting stuck at 2100000 Bytes (~2.1MB)

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, apc

For some odd reason, the apc file upload status gives me the file size until it gets to 2,100,000 at which point it stops.

I am able to successfully upload files smaller than 2.1MB but everything over 2.1MB is failing because of this error. I checked the apc.max_upload_size variable and bumped it up to 100M but still no luck.    I've been monitoring `$status['current']` for a number or different uploads and this number can never get over 2100000.

Something tells me there is some other setting that tells APC to stop reporting back `$status['current']` value after some size has been reached.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was looking for the max size setting in the wrong place.   The 2MB limit was imposed by the php settings so changing that fixed everything!